# Logout user after Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, logout, checkout

using Woocommerce, is it possible to Force a user to be Logged out directly after Checkout (IMPORTANT: I need to have 'Allow customers to create an account during checkout' ticked.)

I ask because by default a user purchases an online course and they get direct access to it despite not being verified by an Admin user.

Comment: So what you want is not the user to be logged out but verified by an administrator?

Comment: You should perhaps rather change the availability of your course product to only verified users somehow, than trying to interfere with the basic login & shop functionality …

Comment: I want a unique user account/password to be created upon each course purchase and for the user to receive these details via email once the Admin user approves their credentials. I have this working except at checkout when Woocommere auto logs-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will logout customer after checkout redirecting customer to shop page:

```
// Logourt after checkout and redirect to shop
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'order_received_logout_redirect' );
function order_received_logout_redirect() {
    // Only on "Order received" page
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        wp_logout(); // Logout

        // Shop redirection url
        $redirect_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id') );

        wp_redirect($redirect_url); // Redirect to shop

        exit(); // Always exit
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

> **Note:** When a customer is logged out, it can't access anymore the order summary (Order received) after checkout, so a redirection is required.

Comment: Understood. Is it possible to update the code to redirect to a specific URL

Comment: This almost works except I need the user to land on a specific URL success page.

Comment: I've created a generic success page... post=265

Comment: For some reason, the above code logs the user out but then ignores the redirect. They're not working together on the site

Answer (score 2):

You can use logout function after checkout  order

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);

function custom_process_order() {   
wp_logout();
}
```

Comment: Adding the above code to my child functions.php seems to work although it's coming up with the following error....  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Also, this prevents the Order Summary from showing.